# scrapy how to select text() or remove white spaces

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

`price_single = hoteldata.xpath("//*[re:match(@id, 'js_item_[0-9]+')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/strong[2]/text()").extract()`

how to get html text without &lrm
because of &lrm i m getting  u'\n        \u200eRs.9,068\n    ', this output
is there any chance to remove that spaces and give Rs.9,068 output

thanks

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pasting some code would be good to see what you tried already. To do this edit your question where you can format your code too.

Comment: @GHajba i added code above

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in price_single:
                print unicode(i).encode('utf-8').split("Rs.",1)[1]
```

i got the answer

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help anyone to understand the problem.

Comment: sorry I m new to the StackOverflow .... problem is getting unicode value ie. u'\n \u200eRs.9,068\n ' but after using above `unicode().encode('utf-8')` i got answer correctaly.